# How to write a Prolog predicate that will return a list of successor facts, sorted by value

Tags: list, sorting, prolog, logic

So I have a predicate called `get_order_successors(L)` and I'm trying to get it to return a list of successor facts, sorted / ordered by ascending value.

An example of this list might look like:

```
 h(a,12).
 h(b,8).
 h(c,4).
 h(d,3).
 h(f,5).
 h(e,5).
 h(g,0).
```

So far this is what I've tried.
Setting up a list like *[[a,12],[b,8],[c,4],etc..]* and running a list search clause like so:

```
on(Item,[Item|Rest]).  

on(Item,[DisregardHead|Tail]):-
          on(Item,Tail).
```

thats purpose is to go through the list, piece by piece, and add the value of that list to a new list, putting it at the start or the front, depending on its value.. but to be honest I feel a little too in over my head with it as I'm quite new to the language and I'm not even certain that that solution will work?

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this problem that I'm just not seeing at the moment. Anybody that thinks they can help would be majorly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a predicate that sets up a list like [[a,12],[b,8],[c,4],etc..] as you described you need to sort the list of lists based on the second element of every inner list. So you need to implement a sorting algorithm (bubblesort,mergesort...) or use the built in sort predicates like `sort/2`:

The problem is that sort/2 could sort a list of lists but based on the 1st element of every inner list, for example:

```
?- sort([[b,2],[a,3]],L).
L = [[a, 3], [b, 2]].
```

so it doesn't give the desired result: `L = [[b, 2], [a, 3]]`.

***How to fix it?***

Just write the predicate that set up the list like:

```
set_up(L):- findall([X,Y], h(Y,X), L).
```

and then:

```
get_order_successors(L):- set_up(L1),sort(L1,L).
```

example:

```
?-get_order_successors(L).
L = [[0, g], [3, d], [4, c], [5, e], [5, f], [8, b], [12, a]].
```

In order to reverse the inner list just write a predicate like:

```
rev([],[]).
rev([[Number, Letter]|T], [[Letter, Number]|T1]):-rev(T,T1).
```

and add it like:

```
get_order_successors(L):- set_up(L1),sort(L1,L2),rev(L2,L).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That has helped a ton. I'm just wondering is there a better way you think I could implement the original list, ie. 
"h(a,12).
 h(b,8).
 h(c,4).
 h(d,3).
 h(f,5).
 h(e,5).
 h(g,0)." 
without having to go for the list within a list way that I was going for above? A more optimal way, that is. Thanks.

Comment: Also, could you tell me how I would flip the final result `"L = [[0, g], [3, d], [4, c], [5, e], [5, f], [8, b], [12, a]]."` so that its letters first, then numbers. ie. `"L = [[g, 0], [d, 3], [c, 4], etc.."`?

Comment: For your first comment I can't think any other obvious way... For your second comment see the edited answer, Glad that helped !!

Comment: Why not use `setof/3` instead of `findall/3` since `setof/3` will sort them for you? `get_order_successors(L) :- setof(X-Y, h(Y,X), L1), maplist(rev, L1, L).` where `rev(X-Y, Y-X).` (note, ordered pairs are generally preferable to two-element lists).

Comment: @lurker, Thank you !! I agree `setof/3` would be more suitable, I just didn't think of it when answering the question but I agree!!! Also I avoided  `maplist/3` since he is a beginner and I didn't want to mess it up and make it difficult... If you want to add a second-alternative answer based on your comment +S(x) from me ;) !!

Comment: Yes, reasonable thoughts for sure. I hesitate on the higher level predicates sometimes, too, for beginners. It's such a nice fit, though. :)

Comment: @lurker Thanks for all your help. But shouldn't the last line:

`get_order_successors(L):- set_up(L1),sort(L1,L2),rev(L2,L).`

have L1 in the end 'rev' predicate like so:

`get_order_successors(L):- set_up(L1),sort(L1,L2),rev(L2,L1).`

Comment: @StephenDunne nope, it shouldn't. If you did that, `L` would be a singleton and uninstantiated after the query to  `get_order_successors(L)` executes. Last term should be `rev(L2, L)` as coder shows in his answer.